# check revents into struct pollfd

Tags: c, linux, system-calls, polling, poll-syscall

According to man(2) poll:

```
int poll(struct pollfd *fds, nfds_t nfds, int timeout);
struct pollfd {
    int   fd;         /* file descriptor */
    short events;     /* requested events */
    short revents;    /* returned events */
};
```

If I write `if(! (fds.revents &1 ))` after using `poll` What does it mean?

Comment: Shouldn't you _know_ why you're writing something like that? Did you get that expression from somewhere else, or what's happening here?

Comment: @AKX I saw that code in another site and I want to understand what does it mean please?

Comment: Maybe you should at least link that other site, then, so we have more context of what's happening there.

Comment: Firstly it means the code is poorly written. Should use the symbolic constants in `poll.h` rather than magic values like `1`. That condition is true if the event corresponding to that bit was either not requested at all or if it was requested but did not occur during the `poll`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [man(2) poll](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/poll.2.html) indeed...

> The field revents is an output parameter, filled by the kernel
> with the events that actually occurred.  The bits returned in
> revents can include any of those specified in events, or one of
> the values POLLERR, POLLHUP, or POLLNVAL.  (These three bits are
> meaningless in the events field, and will be set in the revents
> field whenever the corresponding condition is true.)

`poll.h` defines those as

```
#define POLLIN      0x001       /* There is data to read.  */
#define POLLPRI     0x002       /* There is urgent data to read.  */
#define POLLOUT     0x004       /* Writing now will not block.  */
// etc...
```

so armed with this knowledge,

```
if(!(fds.revents & 1))
```

is the same as

```
if(!(fds.revents & POLLIN))
```

which means "if the "there is data to read" bit is not set", i.e. "if there is no data to read".